# Get ng-model value from ng-repeat input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my app I have `ng-repeat` loop, where I from another list select media and push it to array `medias`. But for every media, I can input custom duration (from media list in object I get predefined media duration, but if we want we can set our custom duration)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="media in medias">
        <span>{{media.title}}</span><br>
        <input ng-model="media.duration" /><br><br>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="getInputValue(media.title, media.duration)">Get</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.medias = [{
  title: 'res1',
  duration: 25.2
},
{
  title: 'res2',
  duration: 15.00
}
];


$scope.getInputValue = function(title, duration) {
alert(title);  //undefined
alert(duration);  //undefined
}
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu6bop6p/)

And, on submit I need to take all custom changed duration and send it to API. 
The first problem is, in my GET button value is `undefined`.
This button needs to be outside from ng-repeat div because I have another data on the page for sending.

I try to put `ng-init`, but this fire on load and after nothing. 
Also, I try `ng-change`, but I have the same name for `ng-model` (because it's dynamically) and with this, I don't know which item I changed.

Idea is, when user change duration for media he wants, on submit I get data and put them in an array like this:

```
//get passed data from ng-repeat
  var mediaCustomDuration = [];
$scope.getInputValue = function(title, duration) {

    mediaCustomDuration.push({
    mediaID: title,
    mediaDuration: duration
 });
//do stuff ...
}
}
```

Comment: ng-click="getInputValue(media.title, media.duration)" is out of repeat scope so this values (media.title and ...) are always undefined. 
So on click you need to iterate over your medias ($scope.medias) and collected data you need. Ng-model insures that your custom duration will be set into the media object and you can pick it

Comment: button is out of scope of ng-repeat. Put it in ng-repeat scope and try.

Comment: Yes, I know submit is `out of box`, i hope there is some directive for this. If I understand you, you mean, when I custom input any media duration without submitting, and on end when I submit all things on the page, iterate over $scope.medias? I will try, thnx.

Comment: @vishugosain i know, in my original question i write that i know it's out of ng-repeat, but I hope there is some solution for this.

Comment: @Arter correct. 
Btw, you can go another way. Easier. 
1. Make button type="submit"
2. Create directive on form ng-submit="submit($scope.medias)"
3. In $scope.submit take medias (they will be already changed) and post them to the remote. 
4. That is all.

Comment: Iterate the array medias using forEach and post it to the API.Make a function to do this and call it on button click.No need for arguments.

Comment: @Vitalii your answer is correct, please move them to  ANSWER soo i can accept them like correct. Thnx

Comment: @Arter 5 minutes please ^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-click="getInputValue(media.title, media.duration)"`

is out of repeat scope so this values (media.title and ...) are always undefined

So here it is two solutions:

On click you need to iterate over your medias ($scope.medias) and collected data you need. Ng-model insures that your custom duration will be set into the media object and you can pick it and send to server.

Another one

1. Make button type="submit"
2. Create directive on form ng-submit="submit($scope.medias)"
3. In $scope.submit take medias (they will be already changed) and post them to the remote.
4. That is all

Hope this helps.